# Search a specific element from array of dictionary using or operator`

Tags: python, mongodb

**Search some specific elements from array of dictionary.**

```
a= [
{"a1" : "1"},
{"a2" : "2"}
]
```

**I need to search the array elements either a1 or a2**

Comment: What needs to be returned if the element is found? Also, please post your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Ananthu, what do you mean exactly? Are searching for the values: You could do this:

```
a= [
{"a1" : "1"},
{"a2" : "2"}
]

search_term='2' 
for item in a: 
    for item,val in item.items(): 
        if val==search_term: 
           print(item)
```

Output:

```
a2
```

You could also search this way:

```
next(item for item in a for item,val in item.items() if val == '2')
```

output:

```
'a2'
```

Comment: `for items in a.items()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to search a list of dictionaries using a given key, and get a list of all the values recovered with this key search?

```
def key_search(mylist, mykey):
    results = []
    for d in mylist:
        try:
            results.append(d[mykey])
        except KeyError:
            pass
    if results:
        return results
    else:
        return [None]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mylist = [{'1':'a'}, {'2':'b'}, {'1':'second'}]
    results = key_search(mylist, '1')
    print(results)
```

This code will return:

```
['a', 'second']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName').find({"$or" : [{"a.a1" : "1"},
                                              {"a.a2" : "2"} ]})
```